# Unknown Menu Bar Item that won't go away

Tags: osx-lion

I just started noticing this menacing and unknown icon in my menu bar. It's a red exclamation mark in a blue circle with a green arrow. Here's an image:

[image: screenshot]

If I click it, whether I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or not while clicking, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: I had no luck with Google Reverse Image Search. It's too small for Tineye... Here's the cropped image I used: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c16FX.png ... The icon suggests that it could be network/download related. Hmm.

Comment: Do you remember installing anything? Does it happen for other users as well? Anything in your Login Items in your user account options?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that the application displaying the icon is Mobile Partner. It is trying to communicate that there is and update for the device. After multiple reboots I was able to click it and get the update process started.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in Activity Monitor for any strange apps. Also try right clicking on it. slhck's advice (looking at the login items in the user accounts pref pane) is also good.